# Hi, I have a problem with this theorem.. If $a$ is transcendental over $F$, then $F(a)\approx F(x)$

Tags: ring-theory

I have a problem with this theorem..

Let $E$ be an extension field of the field $F$ and let $a \in E$. If $a$ is
transcendental over $F$, then $F(a) \approx F(x)$. If $a$ is algebraic over $F$, then
$F(a) \approx F[x]/ p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$ of minimum
degree such that $p(a)= 0$. Moreover, $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

Recall that $F(x)$ is the field of quotients of $F[x]$

According to what I read, $F (a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and the root $a$.

In the theorem say,, If $a$ is
transcendental over $F$, then $F(a)\approx F(x)$.But if $a$ is transcendental over $F$, $a$ is not the zero of some nonzero polynomial in F[x]. then Why $F(a)\approx F(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Let define the following ring morphism: $$\textrm{ev}_a\colon\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}F[x]&\rightarrow&F[a]\\P&\mapsto&P(a)\end{array}\right.$$
Since $a$ is transcendental over $F$, $\textrm{ev}_a$ is injective and extends to an injective morphism from $F(x)$ to $F(a)$. Noticing that $\textrm{ev}_a$ is surjective leads to the result.

Comment: In my book, (Contemporary abstrac algebra-gallian) say: Consider the homomorphism $f:F[x]  ->  F(a)$ given by
$f (x) -> f (a)$. Why u say $F[x]->F[a]$? or what is $F[a]$

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is strange/wrong to call $f$ both the homomorphism and the elements of $F[x]$, this is exactly what I have done. Regarding, $F[a]$, this is simply the set of $P(a)$ for $P\in F[x]$, notice that $F[a]\subseteq F(a)$.